# Qt button press incrementation

Tags: c++, qt, increment, qpushbutton

I am hoping someone can assist me, I have having a bit of an issue. I have a button, in which I want to increment a value as long as it is held down, or pressed

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_pressed()
{
     //sLens->write("4");
}
```

the number that is supposed to be incremented is between 11-66, however one of the biggest issues is that when I hold down the button, it increments once until I let go, then need to click it again to increment by 1. Is there a way in which it would still increment continuously if I hold down the button?

Thank you.

Comment: not sure about the details, but you probably need a loop `while(button.isStillPressed()) { increment(); sleep_for_some_ns(); }`

Comment: I tired the loop however it is just causing the program to crash.

Comment: You need to decide at which speed your value will be incremented, and use a timer that you will start and stop. I don't see any simpler way than creating a subclass of QPushButton and handle the start+stop of the timer in [QAbstractButton::mousePressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#mousePressEvent) and _mouseReleaseEvent_.

Answer (score 2):

`QPushButton` inherits from `QAbstractButton`. `QAbstractButton` has a method named `setAutoRepeat(bool)` so by doing `button->setAutoRepeat(true)` in the constructor of your main window it should work.

Comment: Hi i tried to add `pushButton_4->setAutoRepeat(true);` to the main constructor however it didnt seem to work at all.

Comment: @VijayYadav then please show what you tried and explain what exactly you mean with "didnt seem to work at all".

Comment: Hi i figured it out, i used this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35228598/qt-handling-qpushbutton-autorepeat-behavior-with-isautorepeat).